# When I delete an invitation without responding, does that also send a "no" response to the inviter?

Tags: google-calendar

If I get a calendar invite in Google Calendar, and I delete the invite. Does the invite get updated with a no response?

Comment: Do you get it as email?

Comment: You may find information on the dedicated section for web apps, http://webapps.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quick test shows that if you delete someone's invitation from your calendar (not an email) without responding, then it automatically records this as a "No" response. I invited my other google self to an event. The invitee's view is something like this:

[image: How the invitation appears in the invitee's calendar]

Next, I just deleted the event without responding and the event creator's calendar updated the response to "No".

[image]